# Exposing the same service with same URL but two different ports with traefik?

Tags: amazon-web-services, jenkins, kubernetes, traefik

recently I am trying to set up CI/CD flow with Kubernetes v1.7.3 and jenkins v2.73.2 on AWS in China (GFW blocking dockerhub).

Right now I can expose services with traefik but it seems I cannot expose the same service with the same URL with two different ports.

Ideally I would want expose http://jenkins.mydomain.com as jenkins-ui on port 80, as well as the jenkin-slave (jenkins-discovery) on port 50000. 
For example, I'd want this to work:

`apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: jenkins
  namespace: default
spec:
  rules:
  - host: jenkins.mydomain.com
    http:
      paths:
      - path: /
        backend:
          serviceName: jenkins-svc
          servicePort: 80
  - host: jenkins.mydomain.com
    http:
      paths:
      - path: /
        backend:
          serviceName: jenkins-svc
          servicePort: 50000`

and my jenkins-svc is defined as

`apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: jenkins-svc
  labels:
    run: jenkins
spec:
  selector:
    run: jenkins
  ports:
  - port: 80
    targetPort: 8080
    name: http
  - port: 50000
    targetPort: 50000
    name: slave`

In reality the latter rule overwrites the former rule.

Furthermore, There are two plugins I have tried: [kubernetes-cloud](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Kubernetes+CI+Plugin) and [kubernetes](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Kubernetes+Plugin).
With the former option I cannot configure jenkins-tunnel URL, so the slave fails to connect with the master; with the latter option I cannot pull from a private docker registry such as AWS ECR (no place to provice credential), therefore not able to create the slave (imagePullError).

Lastly, really I am just trying to get jenkins to work (create slaves with my custom image, build with slaves and delete slaves after jobs' finished ), any other solution is welcomed.

Comment: To be able to pull from ECR you can you AWS instance roles with the appropriate permissions. The pull will use instance metadata and work transparently.

Answer (score 1):

If you want your `jenkins` to be reachable from outside of your cluster then you need to change your `ingress` configuration.

Default type of `ingress` type is `ClusterIP`

> Exposes the service on a cluster-internal IP. Choosing this value makes the service only reachable from within the cluster. This is the default ServiceType

You want it type to be `NodePort`

> Exposes the service on each Node’s IP at a static port (the NodePort). A ClusterIP service, to which the NodePort service will route, is automatically created. You’ll be able to contact the NodePort service, from outside the cluster, by requesting :

So your service should look like:

`apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: jenkins-svc
  labels:
    run: jenkins
spec:
  selector:
    run: jenkins
  type: NodePort
  ports:
  - port: 80
    targetPort: 8080
    name: http
  - port: 50000
    targetPort: 50000
    name: slave`